# Error using setval() sequence in databricks for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, databricks, amazon-aurora

I am trying to load the data into Postgres table. In Database, we have a sequence generator defined but it is not associated with in the table ddl. So we need to call sequence generator separately for nextval using `nextval(regclass)` and once all the processing is done we need to set the highest value back to the database sequence using `setval(regclass, bigint)`.

But while doing so my code is not working for `setval(regclass, bigint)`

We have a dataframe of count 10, so the first row sequence should start with the output from `nextval(regclass)` and we need to set the sequence back to `nextval(regclass)+10` after processing the dataframe.

`nextval(regclass)` command is working perfectly fine but getting issue in `setval(regclass, bigint)`

```
seq_query = "select nextval('seq1') as cur_val"
df = df2.option("query", seq_query).load()
```

It is giving me correct result.

```
seq_query = "select setval('seq1',11) as cur_val"
df = df2.option("query", seq_query).load()
df.show()
```

This is giving me the below error.

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 15) (10.130.85.157 executor 1): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: currval of sequence "pm_network_seq" is not yet defined in this session

Comment: The error message is about currval, not setval(). And currval() can only be used after nextval() is used: Returns the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence in the current session.

Comment: Each time I am running setval()/currval() after nextval(), is giving me the same error output.

Comment: Maybe you’re using a different database connection, that would cause an error like this